# I want to convert my TrOCR model into TFLite version

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, transformer-model, huggingface, tflite

How to convert trocr model to TFLite format for use? Haven't attempted yet. Guidance appreciated,
after traned using hugging face tuto, i want to use this generated file in a tnsorflowlite envirenment , how to convert it, and with those generated files